# LyX - undefined control sequence but package seems to be added

Tags: lyx, miktex, mathdesign

I am using LyX with MikTeX and I am trying to use the following command `\oiiint` but I am getting the following error:

```
 \oiiint

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I have added `\usepackage{mathdesign}` to the preamble in:

`Document -> Settings -> LaTeX Preamble`

Why is this not working?

Comment: You must add an option to `mathdesign` for choosing what font family to use; for instance `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}`. Called by itself the package does nothing.

Comment: I tried it using Sublime and it sort of worked, as in it outputted the symbol correctly but I got the following message:

`C:/Users/Colin/Desktop/first.tex:13: Missing $ inserted. [\oiiint]`
`C:/Users/Colin/Desktop/first.tex:14: Missing $ inserted. []`

Comment: Do you have a [minimal example](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample) you can post?

Comment: `\oiiint` has to be placed in math mode, try `$\oiiint$`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that worked great, thanks. If you want to put it up as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: I'd say @egreg answered your original question, so it's more appropriate that he does it.

Comment: That's fair enough, thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing about LyX and how you can eventually accomplish the task with it, but `mathdesign` needs an option for specifying the main typeface to use, for instance

```
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
```

Check in the documentation: `texdoc mathdesign` on a Unix system or [this WEB site](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/mathdesign/mathdesign-doc.pdf).

Note that `\oiiint` is a math symbol, so you have to input it in math mode (inside `$...$` or `\(...\)` if inline, inside `\[...\]`, `equation` or one of the `amsmath` environments if displayed).